# Search multiple strings in sentences

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I try to search "ego d16" in a list like

1. ego fara d16
2. ego d16
3. ego d22
4. d16 ego
5. para ego dela d16

Must result in lines (1, 2, 4, 5)...

My code is

```
var filter = $(this).val(); //like 'ego d16'
$("#rezultate li").each(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].getAttribute('tags').toLowerCase().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show()
    }
});
```

My actual result is only line (2)

How i can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to do a regex for `d16`...

Comment: Should it also match `dela d16` (with no `ego`?)

Comment: no, need to match only sentences with both words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unsimplified code, but it is clean and easy to understand. It should do what you expect. The idea is to split up the input and check which items in the list you gave contain each part of the original input. If a string is missing a part of the input, there's no match.

```
var search = "ego d16"; //Input
var strings = ["ego fara d16","ego d16","ego d22","d16 ego","para ego dela d16"] //Test Strings

var searchItems = search.split(" "); //Array of all separate words in 'search'
var results = []; //Indexes of all matches
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
{
    var inside = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < searchItems.length; j++)
    {
        if (!strings[i].includes(searchItems[j]))
        {
            inside = false;
        }
    }
    if (inside)
    {
        results.push(i)
    }
}
```

It shouldn't be hard to come up with a better method, though

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is simple enough, I think:

```
let list = [
    "ego fara d16",
    "ego d16",
    "ego d22",
    "d16 ego",
    "fred flintstone",
    "para ego dworda d16",
    "para d16"
];
let filters = "ego d16".split(/\s+/);


list.filter(phrase => filters.every(word => phrase.indexOf(word) > -1));
//=> ["ego fara d16", "ego d16", "d16 ego", "para ego dworda d16"]
```

I think this is pretty straightforward.  Let me know if it isn't clear.